# how to globally remove "</br> " from string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i have an html string witch contain many `<br/>`

(with a space after >) how to globally remove them
with javascript

the only way i know is
`mystring = mystring.replace(/somthing/g, "somthingelse");`

but i cant put `<br/>` in //g

Comment: You can try  ```mystring.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"WhatEverYouWantToReplace");```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use '\' in your regular expression to include special character of regex like '/'
here is example

```
const str = "<br/><br/>";
str.replace(/<\/br>/g,"else");
```

Comment: thank you i understand know although i used  `str.replace(/<br\/>/g,"else")` becuse i have <br/> not </br> i made mistake in the title but that really helped me

Answer (score 1):

I don't condone the use of regex for HTML sanitization but assuming you have a legit usecase you need to escape the forward slash:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/<\/br>/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just split the string to remove the `</br>` tag and then join the string again using a character that you want to replace the `</br>` tag with like this:

```js
var mystring = "Hello World</br></br>How are you doing today?</br>Once upon a time in dummy text world</br>";

mystring = mystring.split("</br>").join(""); // replace </br> with an empty string

console.log(mystring);
```